# How to send keyboard and mouse command from host to VMware using autoit?

Tags: vmware, autoit

How to send keyboard and mouse command from host to VMware using autoit?

Is it any other way to workaround?

THanks,
Wa

Comment: Just make sure, the VM is active and use Send(...) or Mouse...(...) commands like in my other [answer](http://superuser.com/a/304583/88327)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to [`WinActivate()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinActivate.htm) your vmware window, then use whatever [`Send()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) and [`MouseMove()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseMove.htm)/[`MouseClick()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm) functions you need.

EDIT:

After `WinActivate()`, do a Send("^g") to gain GUI control of your VM prior to attempting to `Send()` or `MouseMove()` / `MouseClick()` anything else to the VM.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with automating VMware is getting feedback from software running in the guest system. For instance, you cannot wait on a window in a guest by executing WinWait() on the host.

One way to get around that is to implement a master/slave dependency where an AutoIt controller script on the host OS issues commands (via VMware shared folder, a network share, etc) and the AutoIt executor script on the guest OS makes stuff happen and reports back (again, over a share).

An example (simplified, but based on what I'm using right now):

```
WinWait("VMware")
WinActivate("VMware")
Send("{CTRLDOWN}g{CTRLUP}") ; Ctrl+G, give focus to the guest OS
Send("{LWINDOWN}r{LWINUP}") ; Win+R, brings up command entry dialog on the guest
Send("...the actual command with job ID as the argument")
; this last command given to host is actually a compiled AU3 script 
; that does something useful and reports back over a network share
Do
    Sleep(15000) ; now wait for the script on the guest to report back
Until GuestHasResponded()

Func GuestHasResponded()
   ; ... check if the guest has created a flag file on the network share
EndFunc
```

On the other hand, if you simply need to automate the VMware client itself (e.g. automate creation of virtual machines), you can get by with basic AutoIt approach of which examples are plenty on the AutoIt forum.

Comment: You're assuming the VM OS is Windows.

Comment: @Mechaflash, yes. If the Guest is Linux or Mac OS, just send relevant keystrokes. If you are referring to Host, it can only be Windows for this question. As to the Guest not being Windows, there are means of automation specific to other operating systems.